# Getting Paradox linked server OLEDB column type

Tags: sql-server, oledb, linked-server

I have a linked server that is pointing to a Paradox database using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.
I have the issue that the Paradox´s TIME fields are mapped as DATETIME in MSQLS and not as TIME. The same happens to Paradox´s DATE fields.
Because of this, my delphi app is throwing errors.

I need to detect via TSQL the type of the field to differentiate these two types.

Is there any way to get the **ODBC data type** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709362(v=vs.85).aspx) using TSQL?

I tried using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but I just get the SQL Server type.
I also tried with the following query, but just the SQL Server type is displayed:

```
EXEC sp_columns_ex @table_server = 'ParadoxLinkedServer'   
 , @table_name = 'Clients'   
 , @table_schema = NULL--'table_schema'
 , @table_catalog = NULL--'table_catalog'  
 , @column_name = 'EntryTime' 
 , @ODBCVer = '2'
```